# Why is my nested if ignored?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code to find the greatest common denominator using the Euclidean Algorithm.

```
def gcdIter(a, b):

    if a > b:
        if a%b == 0:
            return b
        r = a%b
        a = b
        return gcdIter(a, r)
    elif a < b:
        if b%a == 0:
            return a
        r = b%a
        a = b
        return gcdIter(a, r)

gcdIter(12, 2)
```

Edit: changed (elif b < a) to (elif a < b)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `a > b` is the same thing as `b < a`...

Comment: if remainder of a%b equals zero it doesn't return a or b

Comment: Please don’t change your code after your question has been answered, it will cost confusion to other readers, as the question and answers doesn’t correspond. Post a new question instead. Or if it’s a short and simple addition to your current question, ask it in the comments of an existing answer

Comment: When I edited it, I filled up the edit summary and I thought it will show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As gcdIter is returning a value you need to print it.

```
print gcdIter(12, 2)
```

you can calculate gcd like this as well

```
def gcd(a,b):
    if b==0:
        return a
    return gcd(b,a%b)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your `elif` should be this:

```
elif a < b:
```

As `a > b` and `b < a` is essentially the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

Your elif part will never be reached. If a>b the first if itself satisfies. Change the elif condition to b > a. But for your input gcd(12,2) it should work.

Comment: If you try running this code on pythontutor.com. You will see it will return nothing instead of return b.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this:

```
def gcdIter(a, b):
    if (a < b):
        return gcdIter(b, a)

    # rest of your code
```

In that case you can make sure in your function you'll always have less value for b.

Comment: But that won't return the GCD

Comment: Since for each loop, the remainder should always be divided to b until there is no remainder to get the GCD. I should put comments on my questions next time.